# Retrieve data from MongoDB into Rails Application

Tags: ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4

Instead of Writing whole content into our website.Get Content on our Website from MongoDB in Ruby on rails Application.
That is to show content directly on our website from Database using key value pairs.

How to use key/value(Hashes in Ruby) pairs in MongoDB to get Data into our Rails application.

This is to show up less content and less code in the rails Application.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not entirely clear, however:

- To read and write data in a MongoDB you can use the
  [mongo-ruby-driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver).
- See MongoDB's documentation
  for Rails: [MongoDB Data Modeling and
  Rails](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/model-data-for-ruby-on-rails/).

Comment: My question is to connect to a mongoDB and retrieve the data stored in it into an rails application